# How can I return dynamic array by function parameter?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, return

How can I return values from my_func by parameter? Application crashes during printf. I don't know why, I thought that *abc will be pointer to xxx...

```
void my_func(int *_return)
{
    int *xxx = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) xxx[i] = 100+i;

    _return = xxx;

    return;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int *abc = NULL;

    my_func(abc);
    printf("%d", abc[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make it `std::vector<int> my_func()` and be happy

Comment: Change every occurrence of `_return` to `*_return` (yes, even where you already have one `*` preceding it). In addition, change `my_func(abc)` to `my_func(&abc)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways. The first one is to use references. For example

```
void my_func(int * &a)
{
    a = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) a[i] = 100+i;
}
```

and the function is called like

```
my_func( abc );
```

The second one is to use pointer to pointer. For example

```
void my_func(int **a)
{
    *a = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) ( *a )[i] = 100+i;
}
```

and the function is called like

```
my_func( &abc );
```

In the both cases you should call

```
delete [] abc;
```

when the array will not be needed any more.

Of course you could use `std::vector` instead of the array

```
void my_func( std::vector<int> &v )
{
    v.reserve( 5 );
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) v.push_back(  100+i );
}
```

and the function could be called like

```
std::vector<int> abc;

my_func( abc );
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for that solution, thank You! It's working, I used the second solution...

Comment: You gave me very detailed solutions, thank You again... especially for the pointer-to-pointer... have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) xxx[i] = 100+i;  <<<< i < 5
```

index is till 4, as 5 would be out of bound.

To make it effective you should pass the address of pointer:-

```
my_func(&abc);

void my_func(int**_return)
```

Comment: @mateusz_s: Also change `_return = xxx` to `*_return = xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behavior

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
```

The only valid indexes for an array of length 5 are `[0]` to `[4]`, change your termination condition to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```